# Find nodes until condition using XPath 

Tags: xml, xpath

What expression should I use to find all `td` nodes after the one, which contains text `Foo` or `Bar` and stop before the next `<td colspan="4">` with unknown text. Thanks.

```
<td colspan="4">Foo || Bar</td>
<td rowspan="4">TEXT1</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT2</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT3</td>
...
<td colspan="4">VARIABLE</td>
...
```

UPDATE:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;
use utf8;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $url = 'www.perl.org';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->agent_alias( 'Windows Mozilla' );
$mech->get( $url );

my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

$tree->parse($mech->content);

for my $nodes ($tree->findnodes('//td[
                            preceding-sibling::td
                            [contains(., "Foo") or contains(., "Bar")] 
                            and following-sibling::td[@colspan="4"]
                            ]')) {

    print $nodes->as_text;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
//td[
      preceding-sibling::td
            [contains(., 'Foo') or contains(., 'Bar')] 
      and following-sibling::td[@colspan = 4]
]
```

It will return:

```
<td rowspan="4">TEXT1</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT2</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT3</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this expression work within the HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath because for some reason I don't get results.

Comment: @thebourneid, I have no idea, does it work with ` HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`. I only provide valid standard XPath.

Comment: Ok. I'll do some more testing. You've been very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well with XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 there are the operators `<<` and `>>` that are helpful to express conditions like you have e.g. with XQuery you can nicely write

```
let $tr := <tr>
<td colspan="4">Foo || Bar</td>
<td rowspan="4">TEXT1</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT2</td>
<td valign="top">TEXT3</td>
.....
<td colspan="4">VARIABLE</td>
</tr>
let $td1 := $tr/td[contains(., 'Foo') or contains(., 'Bar')][1]
let $td2 := $td1/following-sibling::td[@colspan = 4][1]
return $tr/td[. >> $td1 and . << $td2]
```

to find the `'td` elements "between" those two other `td` elements.

Obviously with XPath 2.0 you don't have the let and return so you will need to try to stick everything into a single expression:

```
$tr/td[. >> $tr/td[contains(., 'Foo') or contains(., 'Bar')][1] and . << $tr/td[contains(., 'Foo') or contains(., 'Bar')][1]/following-sibling::td[@colspan = 4][1]]
```

where `$tr` is the context node.